# how to get image from image path using angularjs and spring

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I have stored image in a folder and its path in db , while im trying to show the stored image in jsp page using angularjs and spring . It throws following error

> "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/RentdUpload/Images/2/5/68_xc90(3).jpg."

How can i resolve the error and get the image from local folder.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ApplicationContext.xml

> Configure the path where the images are stored in applicationContext.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="file:///C:/Upload/Images/"/>
```

### Temp.jsp

> Call the image from the folder where it saved ,in jsp using the following method

```
<img ng-src="<c:url value="images/{{uploadproductImage1? uploadproductImage1: 'resources/products/assets/images/picture.svg'}}"/>">
```